# What is the dual of $A\cap B$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, adjoint-operators

I encountered with some elliptic problem which admits a variational formulation in terms of space $X$ and I need to understand its dual. Suppose that $2<p<\infty$, $\Omega\subset {\mathbb R}^d$ where $d = 3$ and $|\Omega|<\infty$. $X = H^{2}_0(\Omega)\cap W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. What is the structure of $X^*$?

Comment: What is the topology of $X$?

Comment: @Siminore the usual one in such cases: a sequence converges in $X$ if it converges both in $H_0^2$ and in $W^{1,p}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's the direct sum of the duals of the two spaces, that is,
$$
X^* = \{u + v : u \in H^{-2} , v \in W^{-1,q} \} .
$$

Edit: Correction (see comments below)

Comment: The dual of $H_0^2$ is $H^{-2}$ rather than $H_0^{-2}$.

Comment: @Vladimir - thx, has been corrected

Comment: @HansEngler - Thank You. I had some expectation about $(A \cap B)^* = A^*+B^*$ but failed with the rigorous proof of this fact. I would  appreciate if you provide any source about how it could be done.

Comment: @HansEngler - I have no doubt about $W^{-1, q} = (W_0^{1, p})^*$. But the identity $(W_0^{1, p})^* = (W^{1, p})^*$ cannot be correct.

Comment: I hypothesize that for any $f \in X^*$ exists $f_1$, $f_2 \in L_q$ and $g \in L_2$ such that $$ \langle f, u\rangle = (g, u'')_{L_2} + (f_1, u')_{L_2} + (f_2, u)_{L_2}$$ for any $u \in X$ assuming that equivalent norm in $H^2_0$ is chosen.